# Delete on array crashes C++

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I have below code which is crashing.

```
aClass *ptr_obj = new aClass[5];
delete ptr_obj;
```

I know, ptr_obj is to be deleted using delete[], but my question here is why it crashes when I use delete. I was thinking it will call destructor for first object instead of crash.
Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays allocated with `new[]` **must** be deleted with `delete[]`, otherwise it's undefined behavior.

Change your code to

```
delete[] ptr_obj;
   // ^^
```

> *"but my question here is why it crashes when I use delete."*

Because if you do otherwise, you are calling undefined behavior.

> *"I was thinking it will call destructor for first object instead of crash."*

It doesn't.

Comment: OP says "I know, ptr_obj is to be deleted using `delete[]`", and then asks "why does it crash when I use `delete`?".

Comment: @barakmanos I've been extending on this.

Comment: I would try to provide a practical answer as well ("undefined behavior" is accurate according to the standard, but it doesn't tell you what practically happens). As far as we can tell, using `delete` here should merely cause a memory leak, not a runtime exception. We can guess that something goes wrong in the destructor (which, by the way, should yield the same crash when using `delete[]`). Since the destructor code is missing, you might want to "encourage" OP to add it to the question, and in addition, to describe the behavior when using `delete[]` (which I suspect be the same).

Comment: @barakmanos _"As far as we can tell, using delete here should merely cause a memory leak, not a runtime exception."_ How can we tell this?

Comment: Because we would expect `delete` to take on the first element, and `delete[]` to take on all elements (starting from the first one).

Comment: @barakmanos According to the standard, all _we can expect_ is UB.

Comment: OK, so we're back to square one (avoiding a practical answer). Most users here are OK with that, as can be seen in the up-votes for your answer.